# drf-yasg - read http_method_names from urls.py

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, openapi, drf-yasg

I have a `Settings` subclass of `APIView` which has 2 methods.

```
class Settings(APIView):
    def get(self, request, id=None):
        pass
    def post(self, request):
        pass
```

In `urls.py`, I have the following,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('account/settings/<str:id>', Settings.as_view(http_method_names=['get'])),
    path('account/settings/', Settings.as_view(http_method_names=['post'])),
]
```

As you can see, I want `id` to be passed as a parameter in `get` method, but not in `post` method.

`drf-yasg`, ideally should only show 2 methods on Swagger page, but it shows 4 methods.

```
1. GET for /settings/{id}
2. POST for /settings/{id}
3. GET for /settings/
4. POST for /settings/
```

I have tried adding `@action(methods=['GET'])`, `@api_view['GET']`. But it doesn't work.

How do I tell `drf-yasg` to read allowed methods from `http_method_names` in `urls.py`.

I can keep the `id` as optional, and have only one entry in `urls.py`, but swagger marks it as required on the documentation page.

Also tried but didn't work,

```
@swagger_auto_schema(methods=['put'], responses=schema_doc)
@swagger_auto_schema(method='get', auto_schema=None)
@api_view(['PUT'])
```

Comment: Should the put and get be uppercase?